# Odd perl foreach behavior using pattern matching

Tags: regex, arrays, oracle, perl

I'm writing a perl script that will look at the Oracle 11g database alert log and report errors. The code I'm having an issue with is below:

```
if ($_ =~ (m/WARNING/ or m/ORA/)){print $_ . "\n";}
```

I would expect the if statement (line 31) to produce:

```
Mon Sep 01 01:01:01 1111 WARNING: THIS IS AN ERROR MESSAGE
Mon Sep 04 04:04:04 4444 WARNING: THIS IS ANOTHER ERROR MESSAGE
Mon Sep 05 05:05:05 5555 ORA-123456 HAS OCCURRED.
Mon Sep 06 06:06:06 6666 WARNING MESSAGE!
```

However it's producing:

```
Mon Sep 01 01:01:01 1111 WARNING: THIS IS AN ERROR MESSAGE
Mon Sep 02 02:02:02 2222 log switch has occurred
Mon Sep 03 03:03:03 3333 AUDIT: Purge complete
Mon Sep 05 05:05:05 5555 ORA-123456 HAS OCCURRED.
```

If I use separate if statements for each pattern, I get the desired result:

```
if ($_ =~ (m/WARNING/)){print $_ . "\n";}
if ($_ =~ (m/ORA/)){print $_ . "\n";}
```

I'm at a loss as to why this would be.

**DATA**:

```
Mon Sep 01 01:01:01 1111
WARNING: THIS
IS
AN
ERROR
MESSAGE
Mon Sep 02 02:02:02 2222
log switch
has
occurred
Mon Sep 03 03:03:03 3333
AUDIT: Purge complete
Mon Sep 04 04:04:04 4444
WARNING: THIS
IS
ANOTHER
ERROR
MESSAGE
Mon Sep 05 05:05:05 5555
ORA-123456 HAS
OCCURRED.
Mon Sep 06 06:06:06 6666
WARNING
MESSAGE!
```

**Script**:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = $ARGV[0];
my $output = 'output.out';
my $log_line;
my @log_entries;

open INPUT, $input or die "Could not open $input: $!";
while(<INPUT>)
{
    chomp;
    if ($_ =~ m/^\w{3} \w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{4}/)
    {
        {
            push (@log_entries, $log_line);
        }
        $log_line = "$_ ";
    }
    else
    {
        $log_line .= "$_ ";
    }
}
push (@log_entries, $log_line);
close (INPUT);

foreach (@log_entries)
{
    next if not defined($_);
    if ($_ =~ (m/WARNING/ or m/ORA/)){print $_ . "\n";} #No idea why this doesn't work
#   if ($_ =~ (m/WARNING/)){print $_ . "\n";}
#   if ($_ =~ (m/ORA/)){print $_ . "\n";}
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that Perl had an OR operator....?!

Comment: @Simon Catlin, `or` behaves just like `||`. The difference is that `or` has far lower precedence than `||`. `or` is usually used for flow control (e.g. `open(...) or die $!`). Operators are documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absent a binding operator (`=~` or `!~`),

```
m/.../
```

means

```
$_ =~ m/.../
```

That means that

```
$_ =~ (m/WARNING/ or m/ORA/)
```

means

```
$_ =~ ($_ =~ m/WARNING/ or $_ =~ m/ORA/)
```

So you'll end up doing

```
$_ =~ ''
```

or

```
$_ =~ '1'
```

which is obviously not what you want. Use one of the following instead:

```
$_ =~ m/WARNING/ or $_ =~ m/ORA/
   -or-
/WARNING/ || /ORA/
   -or-
/WARNING|ORA/
```

Comment: Thanks, Excellent answer. I was really struggling with this. That explains why I had to put in:

    next if not defined($_);

I kept getting

    Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string

Answer (score 2):

This is how you combine those two lines together using or operation.

```
if ($_ =~ (m/(WARNING|ORA)/)){print $_ . "\n";}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to define the boolean expression over the match results instead of the match operators - use

```
if (($_ =~ m/WARNING/) or ($_ =~ m/ORA/)) {print $_ . "\n";}
```

instead of

```
if ($_ =~ (m/WARNING/ or m/ORA/)){print $_ . "\n";}
```